# HTML select value access variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Simplified version:
I am trying to make it so the 'select' HTML attribute will call a variable value.
Code:

```
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="button1" value="male">Male<br>

<div id="button2"></div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var male = 'yes';

    $(document).on('click', '#button1', function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('#button2').html(value);
    });

})</script>
```

When the radio button is selected the div "button2" should display 'yes' (the javascript value of the variable 'male').

Comment: what is the value of button1

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/d6J7y/

Comment: @imbondbaby that is the second example, I'm trying to get the first example (where button2 is being set to 'value'  to work the same as setting it manually.

Comment: set button1 value 'yes'

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense... you are just declaring `male` not using it anywhere in your first example

Comment: @This is a simplified version of what needs to be done. In the real version the values would be constantly changing, making manual setting impossible.

Comment: @imbondbaby
The js variable male is being declared so it can be called when button1 is clicked. 
Right now though it is not calling the actual variable, which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: please make your statements/questions clear. it is working perfectly well like @imbondbaby said.

Comment: @Yaje
The code he used set the variable manually. I'm trying to set it 'dynamically' it's two completely different things.

Comment: did you check the fiddle? seriously.

Comment: @Yaje
Yes. Did you? Seriously?
Setting it manually is NOT what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Do like

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 var male = 'yes';

  $(document).on('click', '#button1', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('#button2').html(eval(value));
  });
  })
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d6J7y/1/)

Comment: While that does work, isn't eval like the WORST thing you can possibly use?

Comment: i think there is no alternative here. i tried window[value] its not working for me..

Answer (score 0):

Try Like

```
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function() {        
   $('#button2').html('yes');
});
```